# Python - string value doesn`t apply on second iteration

Tags: python

im currently working on a chat , a client writes a message to the server that server modifies the message and sends the modified message , but it only works on the first message for me

i have tried changing the position of string declaration and more but i could not solve the problem

```
msg = current.recv(1024)

print msg

socket_index = open_client_sockets.index(current) + 1

currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()

new_msg = currentDT.strftime("%H:%M") + " User " + str(socket_index) + ": " + msg

print new_msg
```

Output :

```
hello # good    

12:54 User 2: hello #good  

hello # good   

hello # mistake
```

Comment: this is not the right way to do it. you need to create an API do it by flask or django (flask is better for light weight services)

Comment: @Siyavashvaezafshar Why are you assuming this is HTTP / web stuff?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: We are talking about a chat module. as a user from out side the system there should be an API to call, otherwise how should user sends messages to chat server?

Comment: its python , sorry for not mentioning

Comment: the problem is with the new string not the chat method